# Getting rid of "Expression must be const value" with updated compiler toolchains in C code

Tags: c, compiler-errors, constants

I am trying to compile an open-source C project which is not widely used. I am trying to build it locally with the latest UCRT Microsoft toolchains.

As per documentation, the project should build without any hiccups. But when I tried building, it is failing with some very fundamental errors

[image]

one of the sample problems is with this code:

```
int msg_len = 255;
char msg[msg_len+1];
```

the compiler says that msg_len has to be a const value

```
source_file.c(8): error C2057: expected constant expression
source_file.c(8): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
source_file.c(8): error C2133: 'msg': unknown size
```

I know how to fix this issue. I #defined the msd_len and the problems got fixed. But my problem is how to fix a similar issue with this code where we are not using any direct const values.

```
int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s:%s:%s:%d:%s() %s \n",
            log_strings[loglevel], module, file, line, func, msg);
char fmt[size+1];
```

As a workaround, I am using malloc to allocate arrays, but there has to be some subtle C way of doing  this. Also, this way is not fixing all of my similar errors.

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  C++ does not allow VLA's.  If you want a run time sized array in C++ you use `std::vector`.

Comment: You need a C99-capable compiler.  You're apparently trying to use a C++ compiler that does not support C99.

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh567368(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN looks like only a few C99 features got imported into MS C++.  Gcc has more (see "Variable Length" in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions ), but you may need to jump through a few hoops to use that with UCRT (eg https://mingwpy.github.io/ucrt.html )